# Foreach loop has undefined variable in my view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The error is on the view which says that

> my $audio variable is not defined.

I want  to show everything from the database using a foreach loop.

I tried base on paginate on the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#basic-usage

My controller is below:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Audio_lectures;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function index(){
        $audio = DB::table('audio_lectures')->latest()->paginate();
        return view('welcome', ['audio_lectures' => $audio]);
}
```

The welcome view is below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
      <th scope="col">Download</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($audio as $audio_lectures)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$audio_lectures->id}}</th>
      <td>{{$audio_lectures->subject}}</td>
      <td>{{$audio_lectures->created_at}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{$audio_lectures->filelink}}" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

My route web.php is below:

```
Route::get('/','Audio_lecturesController@index');
```

I expect to show all the audio lectures from my database to my view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one

```
@foreach ($audio_lectures as $audio)
   <tr>
      <td scope="row">{{$audio->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$audio->subject}}</td>
      <td>{{$audio->created_at}}</td>
      <td>
         <a href="{{$audio->filelink}}" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Download</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

> you are passing from controller **audio_lectures** array but you
>   getting as in your view **audio**

Comment: I dont fully understand why your answer is correct but thank you. I did do a var_dump and all the data should have been within the $audio variable. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Nebulanoob look at this link of you're code with more attention ....return view('welcome', ['audio_lectures' => $audio]); ... You'll get to understand.

Comment: @ViperTecPro , sorry to get back to you late but I been looking at it. I am sending array data to the $audio variable. Is this correct? But i dont understand i did not define the variable $audio_lectures. How did it become a variable?

Comment: Alright well, first of all, read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#creating-views , if you don't understand then please let me know I'll help

Answer (score 1):

On your view file looping try this

```
@foreach ($audio_lectures as $value)
   <tr>
      <td scope="row">{{$value->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$value->subject}}</td>
      <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{$value->filelink}}" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Download</a></td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks. it also works. Could you clarify why it works?

Comment: you are passing audio_lectures from your controller return view('welcome', ['audio_lectures' => $audio]);  but you getting as in your view audio you have to use "$audio_lectures" in your view as you passing your $audio with this variable